# SignalR Jquery autogenerated Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, signalr

I have this Code in which there is only Two static div, So i want your kind help to generate new div automatically when new user come. Actually i am working with SignalR.
i need a more divs for new users, and each user have his own div. please provide any of CS or Jquery code help to solve it out. Thanks FOR your help :)

**My index. Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #indicator {
            width: 300px;
            height: 20px;
            background: lightgrey;
            color: black;
            position: absolute;
            left: 500px;
            top: 0px;
        }

        #myshape {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;
        }

        #yourshape {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#indicator").html("connected");
                $("#myshape").draggable({
                    drag: function () {
                        var left = $("#myshape").offset().left;
                        var top = $("#myshape").offset().top;
                        $.connection.moveShapeHub.server.calculate(left, top);
                    }
                });
            });
            $.connection.moveShapeHub.client.updateshape = function (left, top) {
                $("#yourshape").offset({ "left": left, "top": top });
            };
        });
    </script>
    <div id="myshape"></div>
    <div id="yourshape"></div>
    <div id="indicator"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks CrackerOdks, i have a signalR shapemove sampleproject. When i run this project it creates 2 divs, That is right more two user, but i want new div for each user . i mean to say if there is four users there is also four divs. One that is controlled by user and another three are upadated from their owner user, Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the jquery docs on using the append method. That sounds like all you need. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Is .append() method helps to generate new div everytime for new user.
please keep this in mind that My project is SignalR based

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what you are trying to achieve. However, you would need to detect when a new client connection is established and then broadcast an event via signalR which in turn would use the .append jquery method. Look into http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Comment: Thanks jason, I am again explaining the problem..... 
i have signalR project in which there is two divs(described in my code as yourshape, myshape) . the main purpose of this project is to achieve realtime-web response. so every user wants his own div, for example when there is three users there are also three divs, but my project shows only two divs even for more users. SO please provide your best coding skills to help me. I want every user has his own div, e.g 5 user logged in there is also 5 divs. but i have not more than 2 divs :(

Comment: In short i am saying that i need autogenerated of div while user is new user is logged in